# Decouple the class that retrieves data from the parser and from the view updater

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to create a class that handles Flash-PHP client-server communication. Basically, Flash sends (eg after clicking a button in my UI) a variable to PHP and PHP in turn sends a value to Flash.

The class could be similar to the following:

```
package 
{
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    //
    public class CSManager extends MovieClip
    {
        //
        var scriptLoader:URLLoader;
        //
        public function CSManager()
        {
            scriptLoader = new URLLoader();
            scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
            scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);
        }
        //;
        public function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void
        {
            trace("Message sent.");
        }
        //
        public function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace("Message failed.");
        }
        //
        public function sendLoad(variable):void
        {
            var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mydomain/myapp/my.php");
            var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

            scriptVars.var1 = variable;

            scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;

            scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
        }

    }

}
```

So, I imagine that in the body of the method called by the button I instantiate this class and call the CSManager sendLoad method.

As you can see, sendLoad sends data to the server and **two methods handle the result**. 
When data is received the app should **parse the result** and **update a view** but I want to leave this class decoupled from the parser and from the class that updates the view, and use it only to retrieve data from the server. 
**This specifically means I don't want to parse the data and update the view from inside the body of the handleLoadSuccessful method but I want to find a different solution.**

Which could be a good approach to solve this problem?

Edit: I found a [better piece of code](http://code.ericfeminella.com/classes/as3/WebORBPHPRemoteGateway.as.html), but it seems the problem here is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dispatch an event.** *This is one effective technique to decouple your code.*

Your class extends MovieClip, and MovieClip extends Sprite which extends InteractiveObject which extends EventDispatcher. This means that your object is an EventDispatcher and thus can dispatch an event thusly:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event(MYEVENT));
```

In the code that is using this class, you would listen to the event like this:

```
var csManager:CSManager=new CSManager();
csManager.addEventListener(MYEVENT,myHandler);
```

also you'd need the constant string

```
const MYEVENT:String ="MYEVENT";
```

defined somewhere sensible (like as static class property of the CSManager)

Just to clarify, I am not suggesting you call your event MYEVENT, you can change that to something more meaningful like STRAWBERRIES_AND_CREAM or whatever makes sense in your specific context.

Comment: That's a very interesting perspective but how do I get the data coming from the result/fault methods? I'm supposing your idea is to put the dispatch event inside the body of the result/fault method.

Comment: There are two options, one is to make a custom Event class  (extending Event) which holds the data you need, and dispatch an instance of that. The other is to just provide a method/property for the data to be accessed ie on CSManager. This is the simplest solution, and still provides the decoupling you need.

Comment: First of all a little correction to the code you so gently shared with me: in addEventListener it worked for me the string "EVENT", not MYEVENT. I perfectly understood the first option, while the second sounded me a little obscure: could you provide some more insight?

Comment: Yes, MYEVENT was just an example! I suggest you come up with something more meaningful or use one of the many predefined events such as COMPLETE.

Comment: Ok, but the second option explained?   ;-)

Comment: What I mean is: in the code that handles the event you call or a method on the CSManager like getData(). Is that clear enough? Also, I don't understand why you changed it to EVENT. That didn't make a lot of snese.

Comment: Tom, "EVENT" was a temporary name  :-)  I understood what you say, but I prefer the first option. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

have you heard of the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller)? if not, read through the wikipedia page to get a better understanding of this.

you would do the client/server communication in the "model" and after receiving the answer send an event/notification to the view. the model doesn't have to be a movieclip because it has no visual representation - just a normal class. if you want to fire events, you could extend from EventDispatcher

```
public class MyModel extends EventDispatcher
{
   // ...

   private function onDate(evt:Event):void
   {
     // check if data was returned ...
     dispatchEvent(new MyEvent("dataReceived", data);
   }
}
```

and the view should listen for "dataReceived" events.

```
public class MyView extends MovieClip
{
   // ...

   public function MyView(model:MyModel)
   {
     // check if data was returned ...
     model.addEventListener("dataReceived", updateView);
   }

   private function updateView(evt:MyEvent):void
   {
      // parse data and do sth with it
   }
}
```

and you would have a main class in which you instantiate everything:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
   private var model:MyModel;
   private var view:MyView;

   public function Main()
   {
      model = new MyModel();
      view = new MyView(model);
   }
 }
```

or you could use frameworks like [puremvc](http://puremvc.org/) or [robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) - it's a good starting point to build your application on ...

Comment: I know a little MVC even without reading Wikipedia   ;-)  My question strictly regards AS3 and the way you can use it in cases like this one (and reuse the code over multiple projects).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.jonnyreeves.co.uk/2011/04/converting-xml-into-objects-data-marshalling-in-actionscript-3/) about this exact topic - hopefully it will provide some useful reading!  In a nutshell, Tom is bang on the money - have you Loader dispatch a COMPLETE event when the data is ready to collect, a [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) (a class which decouples a View from the rest of your application) can then provide the data to the View.